# Can't calculate the width of a hidden div

Tags: jquery, css

**SOLVED BY VEGA BELOW. [HERE IS THE WORKING FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/dELNa/14/)** I'm keeping the whole post in for future visitors to see how this issue was resolved.

---

I'm trying to create a button that, when hovered, reveals some information on a drawer underneath.

I wanted to make it easy to implement into a page, so I turned it into a jQuery widget. I'd like to have it adjust according to the content on the button and/or on the drawer, **but it's not doing that right now.** The user should be able to put the single HTML div tag with the hidden data, and it'll just work.

Ideally the button/drawer widths would adjust to the max between the two so that the drawer is completely hidden when it is in the closed state. I just don't want my users to have to mess with setting a fixed width.

I need help!

Here's what it'll look like:

[image]

[image]

**Relevant HTML (full HTML in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/dELNa/9/)):**

```
<div class="download" data-value="It's awesome!">Visit Website</div>
```

**Relevant CSS (full CSS in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/dELNa/9/)):**

```
.button {
    position:absolute;
    padding:10px;
}

.drawer {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    left:3px;
    padding:6px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s left ease-in;

}
```

**Relevant jQuery (full jQuery in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/dELNa/9/)):**

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").each(function() {
        $(this).append("<div class='drawer'>" +  $(this).data('value') + "<div class='handle'>||</div></div>");
        $(".drawer", this).css("width", $(".button").width());
    });

    $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".drawer", this).css("left", $(".button").outerWidth());
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".drawer", this).css("left", "3px");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for nice and clean question (and presentation).

Comment: Many thanks :) The better the question, the faster the answer ;)

Comment: A quick fix would be setting a fixed width http://jsfiddle.net/dELNa/10/

Comment: It'd be best if it didn't have to be. This would fix it, but if it could dynamically decide the width of the button and drawer depending on which of the two was longest, that would be better.

Comment: @Jon If it's solved then please mark it as so...

Comment: +1 because I want to use that sexy button idea at some point in the future.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Woops, done. I got sidetracked for a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got to calculate the width based on `this` button. See below,

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").each(function() {
        $(this).append("<div class='drawer'>" +  $(this).data('value') + "<div class='handle'>||</div></div>");
        $(".drawer", this).width($(this).width()); //updated with this object
    });

    $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".drawer", this).css("left", $(this).outerWidth()); //updated with this object
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".drawer", this).css("left", "3px");
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dELNa/11/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help, and willingness to adjust based on my comment. You rock!

Comment: Make sure you click the check mark next to this answer so others know it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".download").mouseenter(function() {
    totalWidth = 0;
    totalWidth  += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    $(".drawer", this).css("left", totalWidth);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".drawer", this).css("left", "3px");
});
```

And that will get the final size of the object plus the value of the delicious contents inside.

Comment: Upvote for "delicious contents inside". Thanks for your answer!